# How to prove that a level set is not a submanifold

Tags: manifolds

I've seen an exercise in which I am to prove that 
$$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2=z^2\}$$
is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I've done a little bit of research and found these answers

[Showing that a level set is not a submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/showing-that-a-level-set-is-not-a-submanifold)

[How to show a level set isn't a regular submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80645/how-to-show-a-level-set-isnt-a-regular-submanifold)

However I still don't understand, how do I exactly prove that a neighboorhood of the origin is not homeomorphic to any open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? I didn't get the 2 vs 4 components thing

Comment: Are you sure you do not know how to verify that it is not locally homeomorphic to $R^3$? Did you try the implicit function theorem to conclude that this set if 2-dimensional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you see that the set you are describing is a double cone? Indeed, for any fixed $z$ the equation describes a circle, and as $z$ varies the radii vary. Thus any neighbourhood $U$ of the origin with the origin removed will be not connected. However if $U$ is homeomorphic to some open $V\subset \mathbb R^2$, then $U-\{0\}$ will be isomorphic to $V-\{v\}$ for some point $v$. However the latter is always connected.

Comment: A double cone, rather.

Comment: Thanks, I had cone first and changed it to paraboloid for some reason... luckily it doesn't matter at all for the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made it clear for me !