# Example of smooth manifold that is the preimage of a critical value for some smooth real-valued function

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am looking for an example of a smooth manifold of dimension $> 0$ that arises as the preimage of a critical value of a smooth function $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. The first comment to the question below ([How to show a level set isn't a regular submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80645/how-to-show-a-level-set-isnt-a-regular-submanifold/80668#comment190511_80645)) gives an argument as to why no such creature exists that seems very plausible to me, but I might be missing something.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $F: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x,y)=x^2$. Then each $(0,y)$ is a critical point, and so $0$ is a critical value. Further, $F^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a line.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple. The preimage of zero under the zero map from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is of course a smooth manifold. The preimage of a critical value can fail to be a manifold, but it doesn't have to.